# How to get the PowerShell equivalent API of SP Server Object Model in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to automate some of the default OOTB functionalities of  SP 2013 Record Center site.How to get access of PowerShell API - methods-properties-equivalent of these in UI OR SSOM. Is there any tool which provides Server Object Model operations described using PowerShell.Any alternative methods to obtain the same in PS.

Answer (score 1):

On the SharePoint server you can launch SharePoint 2013 Management Shell. It loads Microsoft.SharePoint.dll and other libraries, some command lets also. Here you can use whole Server Side object model. You also have helpfull cmdlets like `get-spsite`, `get-spweb` and others. Here are all [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678226.aspx) of them.

Comment: on the top of that, you can use PowerGUI by adding snap-ins for SharePoint, makes your scripting job much easier. http://samirvaidya.blogspot.se/2012/06/how-to-use-powergui-for-sharepoint.html